# Is "White Wine (Sulphites)" halal?

Tags: halal-haram, food

I purchased a prawn linguine from Iceland.  It contains White Wine (Sulphites) 6%, what is this and is it halal?

[image]

Attached Ingredients.

I searched online but couldn't find anything about it.  I have avoided eating the food to be safe, but would like to know what it is.

Comment: There are useful apps for determining this by barcode, like iHalal by iApp on app store

Comment: white wine rendered it haraam.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. It is haram.

*Sulphites*, in parenthesis, is most likely there to indicate that the wine contains sulphites (sulfites).

According to [The Kitchn](http://www.thekitchn.com/the-truth-about-sulfites-in-wine-myths-of-red-wine-headaches-100878) it is used as a preservative in winemaking.

> The term ‘sulfites’ is an inclusive term for sulfur dioxide (SO2). SO2 is a preservative and widely used in winemaking ....

Answer (score 0):

It is highly unlikely that this food contains white wine when you but it. White wine is used when making it, but all the alcohol has evaporated when it was cooked. It therefore no longer contains white wine as such but only some residues of it, as the alcohol and most of the water is not there anymore. What is left of the white wine after cooking the food is not white wine at all and in that respect the list of ingredients is not correct. Compare with bread made with yeast. All the yeast is consumed and transformed into other things when the bread is baked, but still it says in the list of ingredients that one of them is yeast. Ingredients sometimes change into other things when something is cooked or baked.

Comment: Is the conclusion that it isn't haram?

Answer (score 0):

Just because alcohol has a low boiling point doesn't mean it boils away. I'll just copy paste one of my previous comments:

alcohol added to boiling liquid and removed from heat: 85% alcohol retained
alcohol flamed: 75% alcohol retained
no heat, stored overnight: 70% alcohol retained
baked, 25 minutes, alcohol not stirred into mixture: 45% alcohol retained
(source [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooking_with_alcohol#Alcohol_in_finished_food))

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help].